# Click filter in table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter my data in table after click the button.
Here is my filter :

```
app.filter('eyeFilterFunction',function(){
    return function(data, from) {
        if (!from) return data;
        var items = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function(item){
            if(item.weight != from) {
                items.push(item);
            }
        });
        return items;
    };
});
```

And my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/s7tuhKXFSt0Yv5BfI4h0?p=preview

What i want - after click the button, only shows in table data with `weight` , where it is `null` in `wehgit` let it not show.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
app.filter('eyeFilterFunction',function(){
    return function(data, from) {
        if (typeof from === 'undefined') return data;
        var items = [];
        for(var x of data){
          if(x.weight != from){
            items.push(x);
          }
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

Comment: and now how to remove this filter?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

http://plnkr.co/edit/jNid2ZwiDNLrwGx2rnKh?p=preview9rnKsXvEtJrxhOYDMa7o?p=preview

```
app.filter('eyeFilterFunction', function() {
  return function(data, from) {
    if(!from) return data;
    return data.filter(i => i.weight != null);
  };
});
```

in template,

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in messages | eyeFilterFunction:filterText">
```

the button,

```
<button class="btn btn-clear btn-sm" ng-click="filterText = !filterText">Filter!</button>
```